# dup2 before fork works but not after... why?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a string on a pipe, fork and execute grep from the pipe's string.
Just trying stuff out in order to understand pipe, fork and dup.
I got it to work, but I don't understand why it doesn't in the first example.
-> Points to the difference in both codes.

Thank for the help in advance!

DOESNT WORK

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    int out = dup(1);

    pipe(fd);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);                           //swapping stdout for pipe write
    close(fd[1]);
    write(1, "ola\nmundo\n", 9);
    int pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0)
    {
->      dup2(out, 1);                    //replacing terminal's stdout
        dup2(fd[0], 0);                  //swapping stdin for pipe read
        close(fd[0]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "n", NULL);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);               
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't output anything on terminal or finish executing.

WORKS

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    int out = dup(1);

    pipe(fd);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);                           //swapping stdout for pipe write
    close(fd[1]);
    write(1, "ola\nmundo\n", 9);
->  dup2(out, 1);                             //replacing terminal's stdout
    int pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0)
    {

        dup2(fd[0], 0);                  //swapping stdin for pipe read
        close(fd[0]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "n", NULL);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);               
    return 0;
}
```

outputs whats expected: "mundo\n" on terminal.

Comment: What is your expectation and observed result ("works"/"doesn't work")? Do all `dup/dup2/write` functions return success?

Comment: i expect grep to output on terminal with "mundo\n". it works if dup2 is not on the child process. when it doesnt work, the program doesnt print anything and doesnt finish executing. i also found out that if i close(1) after write it works. but this just isn't making sense to me.

Comment: *>if i close(1) after write it works* Pipe is block-buffered by default.

Comment: I can't understand why so many `dup()`s. Are you trying to implement `popen()`-like functionality? Why do you write to `1` instead of `fd[1]` then? Child process inherits all file descriptors by default, stdout too. So output of `grep` will be placed to the pipe.